# proxy omit the Range field in the POST request

Tags: html

we use POST request to upload data to our own webserver which is not implemented obey the strictly HTTP standard.And we add the Range field in the POST request to tell our server the offset of the uploading file and now we found that some proxy omit this field.Is this a standard way?I looked up the RFC and didn't find out it's invalid to use Range in the POST request.How can i solve this problem?Any advance will be preciated.